# need help with conditional gdb debugging (of C code)

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I have a C code similar to:

```
int f() {
   for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
   scanf flag;
   if(flag) 
      scanf data1;
   scanf data2;
   }
}
```

I want to break the execution only when `flag == 0`. How should I set the breakpoint (using gdb)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the gdb console type

```
b (some_line) if flag == 0
```

EDIT:
If you can't `print flag` while stopped at *some-line*, then either:
- (A) your code is compiled with optimization (likely), or
- (B) you have a buggy compiler

If it's (A), add `-O0` in addition to `-g3`.

If you *can* `print flag`, then you have a buggy version of `GDB`. Try upgrading to current 7.0.1 release.

Comment: yes, i tried that already...

I am getting `Error in re-setting breakpoint 17:
No symbol flag in current context.`

Comment: @dksjalk Have you compiled with debug information? gcc -g myfile.c

Comment: @dksjalk: or better — gcc -g3

Comment: yes, I compiled with debug information (using Eclipse though), but I am not sure the debug info is there. Is there some way to check?

Comment: @dksjalk The error you are getting is exactly the one you get if there is no debug info.